# What is the difference between 気がする and 気はする?

Tags: grammar

What would be the difference in meaning between:

> 富と名声とか、そういったのを求めている人達と中身は変わらないような**気はちょっとするんだけど。**

and

> 富と名声とか、そういったのを求めている人達と中身は変わらないような**気がちょっとするんだけど。**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a subtle difference in nuance, if not in meaning, between the two.

By sayng 「気**は**する」, you would sound just a little bit less sure of what you are saying than when you use 「気**が**する」.

Even adding a word like 「ちょっと」 would not really change the degree of "sureness" expressed by 「気**が**する」.